# fatal error: module 'audioplayers_darwin' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-ios-build

My Flutter app is working fine for Android devices and simulators and when I try "flutter run" with iOS simulator... I get the following error...

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           1,891ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         6.4s
Xcode build done.                                           40.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/9k/fjjtmhcd3l7gjlmf46bwrhqh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.ooU1om/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirGCaWjd/temporary_xcresult_bu
        ndle

    /Users/rishigesan/Documents/GitHub/atreus/vway_taxi/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error: module
    'audioplayers_darwin' not found
    @import audioplayers_darwin;
```

I can't figure out what to be done to resolve this issue...

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out in the meantime? Experiencing the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! I didn't configure Podfile properly

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by Installing **Cocoapods** using **HomeBrew**